# mapping keys (all occur in the given string) to the position in string

Tags: python

I am trying to get all indexes of the keys in the string and store them in a dict, so that
every index has a list of keys mapping to it.

Example:

```
string = "loloo and foofoo at the foo bar"
keys = "foo", "loo", "bar", "lo"
```

i expect something like

```
{ 
  0: [lo]
  2: [loo, lo]
 10: [foo]
 13: [foo]
 24: [foo]
 28: [bar]
}
```

My current answer loos the following:

```
def get_index_for_string(string, keys):
    """
    Get all indexes of the keys in the string and store them in a dict, so that
    every index has a list of keys mapping to it.
    """
    key_in_string = dict((key, [m.start() for m in re.finditer(key, string)])
                            for key in keys if key in string)
    index_of_keys = {}
    for key, values in key_in_string.items():
        for value in values:
            if not value in index_of_keys:
                index_of_keys[value] = []
            index_of_keys[value].append(key)
    return index_of_keys
```

Any suggestions on how to make this better?

Comment: What have you [done?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @jakob-bowyer i wrote down my solution. Do you think it can be improved?

Comment: Try migrating this question to the [code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) if you just want a general code review. This site is for specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

`Non-regex` approach:

using `str.find()`, `str.find()` accepts a optional second argument which is the index after which you want to find the word.

```
def indexes(word,strs):
    ind=0                #base index is 0
    res=[]
    while strs.find(word,ind)!=-1:   #loop until str.find() doesn't return -1
        ans=strs.find(word,ind)
        res.append(ans)
        ind=ans+1                 #change base index if the word is found
    return res     

strs = "loloo and foofoo at the foo bar"
keys = ["foo", "loo", "bar", "lo"]

print {x:indexes(x,strs) for x in keys}
```

**output:**

```
{'lo': [0, 2], 'foo': [10, 13, 24], 'bar': [28], 'loo': [2]}
```

Comment: i think the regex approach is neater here. also your output is not as the asker requested

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you'll want to `re.escape` the key in case it contains periods or anything like that. Besides that, you can take a more direct approach constructing your result dict:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def get_index_for_string(string, keys):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for key in keys:
        for match in re.finditer(re.escape(key), string):
            res[match.start()].append(key)
    return res
```

Note: Instead of using `defaultdict` you could also use a regular dict and do `res.setdefault(match.start(), []).append(key)`, but it doesn't look as pretty.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of "better" are you looking for? If you need better Big-O complexity, go with [Aho-Corasic Automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm). There are fast implementations available for Python:

- https://github.com/scoder/acora
- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ahocorasick